# 3D arc in Asymptote

Tags: diagrams, 3d, technical-drawing, asymptote

I constructed the technical figure embedded below. I wonder how to draw red arc to denote angle `$\alpha$` between two blue vectors. (Actually, I add the desired output using Inkscape.)

[image]

The Asymptote code is pasted below.

```
import three;
import graph3;
size(200);

pen solid=linetype(new real[]);
pen longdashed=linetype(new real[] {10,8});
pen dashed=linetype(new real[] {3,8});

currentprojection=perspective(1/2,-1/4,1/4.4);

pen bg=gray(0.9)+opacity(0.1);
draw(surface((0,0,0.5)--(1,0,0.5)--(1,1,0.5)--(0,1,0.5)--cycle),bg);

draw((0,0,0)--(1,0,0), solid);
draw((0,0,0)--(0,1,0), longdashed);
draw((1,0,0)--(1,1,0), solid);
draw((0,1,0)--(1,1,0), longdashed);
draw((0,0,1)--(1,0,1), solid);
draw((0,0,1)--(0,1,1), solid);
draw((1,0,1)--(1,1,1), solid);
draw((0,1,1)--(1,1,1), solid);
draw((0,0,0)--(0,0,1), solid);
draw((1,0,0)--(1,0,1), solid);
draw((1,1,0)--(1,1,1), solid);
draw((0,1,0)--(0,1,1), longdashed);
draw((0.5,0,0.5)--(0.5,1,0.5));
draw((0,0.5,0.5)--(1,0.5,0.5));
draw((0,0,0)--(1,1,1),dashed);
draw((1,0,0)--(0,1,1),dashed);

// Blue vectors
draw((0.5,0.5,0.5)--(1,1,1),blue,Arrow3);
draw((0.5,0.5,0.5)--(1,0.5,0.5),blue, Arrow3);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

Change the end of your `MWE` to

```
// Blue vectors
guide3 v1=(0.5,0.5,0.5)--(1,0.5,0.5);
guide3 v2=(0.5,0.5,0.5)--(1,1,1);
draw(v1,blue,Arrow3);
draw(v2,blue,Arrow3);
guide3 alphaArc=arc(point(v1,0),point(v1,0.5),point(v2,0.5));
draw(alphaArc,red,Arrows3);

label("$\alpha$",alphaArc,SE);
label("$e_1$",point(v1,1),SE);
label("$e_2$",point(v2,1),SE);
```