# Why the angle in oblique(the angle) only from 0 to 90?

Tags: asymptote

These are things I try

```
settings.outformat="pdf"; 
settings.prc=false;
settings.render=0;

import graph3;
unitsize(1cm);
size(12cm);
defaultpen(fontsize(12pt));
defaultpen(linewidth(1pt));

currentprojection=obliqueY(30);

path3 anglearc(real radius, triple A, triple B, triple C) 
{ // % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321685/arcs-in-3d-asymptote
triple center = B;
triple start = B + radius * unit(A-B);
return arc(center, start, C,cross(A-B, C-B),CCW);
}

draw(Label("obliqueY(30)",align=2*dir(10)),anglearc(0.2,(1,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,1,0)),Arrow3(size=3));
dot("$(1,1,1)$",(1,1,1),align=2N);
dot("$(1.5,0,0)$",(1.5,0,0),align=2S);
dot("$(0,0,1.5)$",(0,0,1.5),align=SE);
dot("$(1.5,0,1.5)$",(1.5,0,1.5),align=2N);
draw((1.5,0,0)--(1.5,0,1.5)--(0,0,1.5),dashed);
limits((-1,-1,-1),(2,2,2));
xaxis3("$x$",Arrow3); 
yaxis3("$y$",Arrow3);
zaxis3("$z$",Arrow3);

shipout(bbox(2mm,invisible));
```

[image]

With `oblique=135`, the axis y is drawn at `oblique=45` and `(1,1,1) is coincides with (1.5,0,1.5)`

[image]

Question:

In the documentation, I see `The point (x,y,z) is projected to (x+0.5y,z+0.5y)`, with my code, how can I understand?

If I fail, please give me an example to illustrate.

Comment: Could you turn your code fragment into a full “minimal working example” (MWE), ie the full file contents including the document class, package imports, etc? That makes it much easier for readers to quickly test/modify your code and attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat: my mistake, I hadn’t realised asymptote was a standalone system rather than an embedded language within TeX!  My apologies to OP.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug, or at least a somewhat unexpected feature (if the term "oblique projection" is not used in practice with obtuse angles; I don't know whether that is the case.).

In the [definition of `obliqueY`](https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/blob/63e57e22672ef485fafbe6cb207e03a4d4d30e66/base/three.asy#L391), the angle is used only in this line as far as I can tell:

```
real c2=Cos(angle)^2;
```

Since `$\cos \theta = -\cos (180^{\circ} - \theta)$`, obtuse angles are treated as their acute supplements.

I suggest filing a bug report at https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/issues.